# Designing HTML email for Outlook 365 - Email will not align center

Tags: html, responsive-design, outlook, html-email

I am having a real problem designing/coding this email for Outlook 365. The below code works for centering an email in all other email applications, except Outlook 365. Does anybody know a work-around?

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="wrapper" bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" width="100%" bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="page" style="text-align:left;">
```

Comment: I don't see any problems - http://jsfiddle.net/86dua/

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set an actual width to the table.  For example `width="900"`and add `style="margin:0 auto"` so that your table centers on page.

Comment: I can try that, but I think putting an actual width will make the whole thing unresponsive with mobile.

Comment: So, to clarify, if a user checks their Gmail on their mobile, you want your emails to be responsive?

Comment: I didn't hear any mention of Gmail, but I know where this conversation is headed... Gmail doesn't support media queries, so you'll have to stick to fluid or aligning (floats) if you want 100% client support. [More info here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604300/responsive-emails-on-gmail-app-android/13611105#13611105)

Answer (score 0):

Put `align="center"` in your child table as well. Outlook treats it similar to float, so it needs to be on the children.

On a side note, to align the content within that child table, use align on its `<td>` elements.

Here is a [basic html email setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22819973/100-table-width-for-html-email/22820818#22820818) with centering to get you started