# How to display images within html email content in gmail?

Tags: html-email

In yahoomail and html email, the images are loading but not in gmail. I observed that in gmail, the image urls are altered.

For example,

Image URL in yahoo/Hotmail : http://qaecmwcs.qacorp.moneygram.com/sites/Satellite?blobcol=urldata&blobkey=id&blobnocache=true&blobtable=MungoBlobs&blobwhere=1515690635784&ssbinary=true

Url for the same image in Gmail : https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/2B2Fyk0aboH-eiikaxVWdIC9DXbJzhZEuWKm5yPwUeXf3SdYRuoKBGT-HeCFRlNcg7VTzljtSsEhHkikFMGPac35C6Az2Fc2wsdig3xj0S3g1bEIABaMx9RKnTjYuqagP1hUGNl3GG4f2aHy26wHrINZkdn5Wv3y6zcvbWHUL8rabUcjHuCO05i8RM31x8iFJmUorccqIJM6P9f6-eLIaQ5GpZYCrKPJws72HfM2-AsXcg=s0-d-e1-ft#*http://qaecmwcs.qacorp.moneygram.com/sites/Satellite?blobcol=urldata&blobkey=id&blobnocache=true&blobtable=MungoBlobs&blobwhere=1515690635784&ssbinary=true*

When I manually remove the additional url part in the image src,from DevTools then I am able to see the image. Can any one please let me know how I can handle this in gmail?

Comment: Why is this question under-rated? I have given the examples and details correctly. I have been looking for help for this issue but is marked underrated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The firewall was blocking the images from displaying. When client opened the firewall then the images within the server are loaded.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an image to work in email, it has to be viewable by your audience. The image path should be straightforward and simple. What you have posted over and over in your questions are images that are not accessible to the general public, so they will never work for an email.

**Image Path**

This is how an image should be formatted:

```
<img src="staticpath" alt="imagename" class="imageclass" />
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" width="104" height="142" alt="W3Schools.com">
<img src="https://placehold.it/600x600" height="600" width="600" />
```

**More information**:

- https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp

**Image Descriptors**

As a best practice, an image path should end in a descriptor that defines what the format of the image. Images that work well with emails include `.jpg` `.png` `.gif`.

**More Information**:

- https://litmus.com/blog/png-gif-or-jpeg-which-ones-should-you-use-in-email

**Email Templates**

Your email templates should follow the basic practices of a well-formatted html page. Email development is not Web development because email clients do not support current html 5 or css 3 standards. So it can be very hit and miss to create a complex email.

The following email templates will give you a good idea how an email should be created, how images should look, how image classes work.

**Email template Examples**:

- http://tedgoas.github.io/Cerberus/
- https://foundation.zurb.com/emails/docs/v1.0.5/index.html

Please take the time to read through this answer, read through the attached examples.

- [Best Practices & Considerations when writing HTML Emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229822/best-practices-considerations-when-writing-html-emails)

Good luck with your images.