# How to create a three column grid using css?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I'm trying to create a 3 column grid for an email template that uses the liquid template language.

A lot of users use Outlook. I am trying to use a table for the grid which is working okay, but I can't get the images to look good. I either use a CSS command that doesn't render in Outlook or it looks really terrible.

This is what works but won't render in Outlook:

```
<td>
  <div style="padding: 5px;">
    <img style="width: 100%; height: 150px; object-fit: contain; object-position: center;" src="/images/logo1.png" />
  </div>
</td>
```

How can I turn this 'sentence' into something that will render for all email clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally bad practice to use `<div>` elements when working with HTML E-mails. You should refer to strictly using `<table>` layout instead to get your desired results. The reason for this is that many E-mail clients simply don't support anything else. Other than that, some E-mail clients will also ignore inline padding and margin styling on `<img>` elements, as well as some other specific stuff. It really all depends. Rule of thumb is, as long as you use a `<table>` layout, you're probably fine. For the most part anyways.

[This old article](https://web.archive.org/web/20120204041931/https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3472/div-tags-in-html-email-newsletters/) covers some of the inconveniences with the `<div>` element in HTML E-mails.

Alternatively, check out [this article](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/how-to-code-emails-for-outlook-2016/) on Outlook 2016 HTML E-mail tips.

I would also **highly** recommend navigating through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229822/best-practices-considerations-when-writing-html-emails/21437734#21437734) gem of a post if you're interested in learning more about HTML E-mails.