# why isn't outlook desktop rendering html as intended?

Tags: html, css, outlook, power-automate

so why isn't outlook desktop rendering these highlighted columns? Not too familiar with HTML/CSS so a little lost. This shows in my web browser with highlighted columns. My understanding is colgroup is supported by the rendering engine so i'm not sure what im missing. thanks

```
<table>
   <colgroup>
      <col style="background-color:#FFFF00">
      <col>
      <col>
      <col>
      <col>
      <col style="background-color:#FFFF00">
      <col style="background-color:#FFFF00">
      <col>
      <col>
      <col style="background-color:#FFFF00">
      <col style="background-color:#FFFF00">
      <col>
   </colgroup>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Pro Number</th>
         <th>Date</th>
         <th>Est Delivery Date</th>
         <th>Origin</th>
         <th>Destination</th>
         <th>Terms</th>
         <th>Total A/R</th>
         <th>Responsible Account</th>
         <th>Responsible Customer</th>
         <th>Responsible Name</th>
         <th>Responsible Risk Code</th>
         <th>Responsible Analyst</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>123456789</td>
         <td>2021-11-24</td>
         <td>2021-11-29</td>
         <td>LOU</td>
         <td>CIN</td>
         <td>Collect</td>
         <td>1000</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>Sample Customer</td>
         <td>CASH ONLY - NO BUSINESS ALLOWED</td>
         <td>Sample Analyst</td>
      </tr>

 
   </tbody>
</table>
```

edit: i tried without col and colgroup and this works. just need to be able to do this with a dynamically changing table for every row.

```
<table>

   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Pro Number</th>
         <th>Date</th>
         <th>Est Delivery Date</th>
         <th>Origin</th>
         <th>Destination</th>
         <th>Terms</th>
         <th>Total A/R</th>
         <th>Responsible Account</th>
         <th>Responsible Customer</th>
         <th>Responsible Name</th>
         <th>Responsible Risk Code</th>
         <th>Responsible Analyst</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td bgcolor="#FFFF00">123456789</td>
         <td>2021-11-24</td>
         <td>2021-11-29</td>
         <td>LOU</td>
         <td>CIN</td>
         <td bgcolor="#FFFF00">Collect</td>
         <td bgcolor="#FFFF00">1000</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td bgcolor="#FFFF00">Sample Customer</td>
         <td bgcolor="#FFFF00">CASH ONLY - NO BUSINESS ALLOWED</td>
         <td>Sample Analyst</td>
      </tr>

 
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: My guess is that col and colgroups aren't supported by the outlook engine. All email providers offer different support. A rule of thumb is to simply always use standard table markup and inline styling to be 100% covered on all bases. I aggregated some links to a previous answer about HTML Emails here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62400749/cant-get-css-right-for-outlook-email/62401031#62401031

Comment: thanks @Martin, i tried another approach and this seems to work. i just need to be able to highlight every row for the specific columns. My sample was just for 1 row, but in the end this table size will change daily.

Comment: I think, "use tables" is the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to settle for highlighting the headers. Outlook desktop uses an old rendering engine that seems to only work with inline css

```
         <th  style="background-color:#FFFF00">Pro Number</th>
         <th>Date</th>
         <th>Est Delivery Date</th>
         <th>Origin</th>
         <th>Destination</th>
         <th  style="background-color:#FFFF00">Terms</th>
         <th  style="background-color:#FFFF00">Total A/R</th>
         <th>Responsible Account</th>
         <th>Responsible Customer</th>
         <th  style="background-color:#FFFF00">Responsible Name</th>
         <th  style="background-color:#FFFF00">Responsible Risk Code</th>
         <th>Responsible Analyst</th>
```