# VS Code and my browser displays this email signature properly, but none of the applications I've tested shows it correctly

Tags: html, css, image, email, signature

Basically the title. I use eM Client, my client uses Outlook and I've tested it in iCloud web as well. None displays the signature correctly but VS Code and all my browsers does. Unsure why and what to do at this point. Note that I'm a designer, so I used auto-layout in Figma and used that code to get to this file. The file looks like this (please remember I'm very new to this, so it might be messy):

```
<html>
  
  <head>
    
    <title>Compucable email-signature</title>
    <style>  
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik:300,700,italic"); 
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css");

html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}
button:focus-visible {
  outline: 2px solid #4a90e2 !important;
  outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px !important;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.email-signature {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 758px;
  min-height: 162px;
}


.email-signature .info {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 131px;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.email-signature .name-and-logo {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 10px;
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.email-signature .div {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 5px;
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.email-signature .j-d-van-der-walt {
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
  margin-top: -1.13px;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(43, 145, 209) 0%, rgb(41, 196, 169) 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text !important;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  font-family: Rubik, Helvetica;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: transparent;
  font-size: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: normal;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.email-signature .operations-director {
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
  font-family: "Rubik", Helvetica;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
  color: var(--blue);
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: normal;
  white-space: nowrap;
}


.email-signature .links {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 10px;
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.email-signature .div-2 {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 5px;
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}


.email-signature .flexcontainer {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 2px;
}

.email-signature .text {
  position: relative;
  align-self: stretch;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-family: "Rubik", Helvetica;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: var(--blue);
  font-size: 8px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: normal;
}

.email-signature .text-wrapper {
  font-family: "Rubik", Helvetica;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #003366;
  font-size: 8px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
}

.email-signature .div-3 {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 5px;
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.email-signature .text-wrapper-2 {
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
  font-family: "Rubik", Helvetica;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: var(--blue);
  font-size: 8px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: normal;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

:root {
  --white: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  --blue: rgba(0, 51, 102, 1);
  --teal: rgba(0, 128, 128, 1);
  --orange: rgba(184, 115, 51, 1);
  --grey: rgba(211, 211, 211, 1);
}


    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="email-signature">
      <img alt="Icon with compucable logo" style="position: relative;
  width: 132px;
  height: 132px;" 
  src="data:image/png;base64,imagecodehere>
      <div class="info">
        <div class="name-and-logo">
          <div class="div">
            <div class="j-d-van-der-walt">J.D. Van Der Walt</div>
            <div class="operations-director">Operations Director</div>
          </div>
          <img alt="compucable logo" style="position: relative;
  width: 245px;
  height: 16px;"
src="data:image/png;base64,imagecodehere>
        </div>
        <div class="links">
          <div class="div">
            <div class="div-2">
              <img alt="address icon" style="position: relative;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;"
src="data:image/png;base64,imagecodehere>
              <div class="flexcontainer">
                <p class="text">
                  <span class="text-wrapper">PTA: </span>
                  <a href="tel:0123429160" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"
                    ><span class="text-wrapper">012 342 9160<br></span
                  ></a>
                </p>
                <p class="text">
                  <span class="text-wrapper">CPT: </span>
                  <a href="tel:0212073977" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"
                    ><span class="text-wrapper">021 207 3977</span></a
                  >
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="div-2">
              <img alt="address icon" style="position: relative;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;"
src="data:image/png;base64,imagecodehere>
              <a href="https://maps.app.goo.gl/JXRQiR4KMZ8LLnv9A" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"
                ><div class="flexcontainer">
                  <p class="text">
                    <span class="text-wrapper">1028 Pretorius Street,<br></span>
                  </p>
                  <p class="text">
                    <span class="text-wrapper">Hatfield, Pretoria, 0002</span>
                  </p>
                </div></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="div">
            <div class="div-3">
              <img alt="address icon" style="position: relative;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;"
src="data:image/png;base64,imagecodehere>
              <a href="mailto:info@compucable.co.za" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"
                ><div class="text-wrapper-2">info@compucable.co.za</div></a
              >
            </div>
            <div class="div-3">
              <img alt="address icon" style="position: relative;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;"
src="data:image/png;base64,imagecodehere>
              <a href="https://www.compucable.co.za" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"
                ><div class="text-wrapper-2">www.compucable.co.za</div></a
              >
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I started with SVG but apparently Oulook doesn't support that (??) and then decided to encode the images with base64. Not sure what to do next.

[broken signature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UiST.jpg)

I saw some things about using tables for email signatures. Honestly not sure how to do that, if I should start from scratch? Can you add images into tables?

Comment: Email programs are typically very limited in the HTML and CSS that they support, see e.g. https://mailchimp.com/help/limitations-of-html-email/. Forget the ever-evolving browser landscape, think HTML4 or perhaps even less than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh! Yes, unfortunately, email layout is stuck back in 2004.

Therefore, you should use tabular layout to work with emails. This is so much fun! (**No**)

**No svg, unfortunately.** Any svg - is just a small png picture that is hosted statically on your server, and a link to it is inserted in the email.

It is also necessary that all your **styles are inlined**. You can write code in scss, which you transform into css, which then `gulp` will take, for example, and convert your HTML and CSS into one inlined layout.

You can also attach some `@media css` rules in the style tag along with your email, but only half of the email services will read them, so write in such a way that everything looks beautiful on both mobile and desktop at the same time.

There are a lot of rules and recommendations on how to write beautiful emails, I’ll share a couple of useful links:

- [Which css props u can use](https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=max-width)
- [Best Practices & Considerations when writing HTML Emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229822/best-practices-considerations-when-writing-html-emails/21437734#21437734)
- [Testing your email displaying and sending](https://app.postdrop.io/)
- Use em instead of px

And this gulp tool, that will help you make correct emails:

**package.json:**

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "gulp buildEmail"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-email-builder": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

**gulpfile.js:**

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const emailBuilder = require('gulp-email-builder');

gulp.task('buildEmail', function () {
  return gulp
    .src(['./src/emails/*.html'])
    .pipe(emailBuilder().build())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/emails/'));
});
```

That's all, put your html emails into `./src/emails/`, take it from `./dist/emails/`

Comment: Thank you so much, built the whole thing again with tables. Only almost started crying! Pretty sure I fixed it, shows up fine for me and the client now.

Comment: I undestand your pain, bro ❤️‍ @RiaanGreeff

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating email template than try to create using table and yes you can add image to table.

```css
.container {
  padding: 2rem 0rem;
}

h4 {
  margin: 2rem 0rem 1rem;
}

.table-image {
  td, th {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <table class="table table-image">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Day</th>
              <th scope="col">Image</th>
              <th scope="col">Article Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Author</th>
              <th scope="col">Words</th>
              <th scope="col">Shares</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">1</th>
              <td class="w-25">
                  <img src="https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bootstrapbaymisc/blog/24_days_bootstrap/sheep-3.jpg" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" alt="Sheep">
              </td>
              <td>Bootstrap 4 CDN and Starter Template</td>
              <td>Cristina</td>
              <td>913</td>
              <td>2.846</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">2</th>
              <td class="w-25">
                  <img src="https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bootstrapbaymisc/blog/24_days_bootstrap/sheep-5.jpg" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" alt="Sheep">
              </td>
              <td>Bootstrap Grid 4 Tutorial and Examples</td>
              <td>Cristina</td>
              <td>1.434</td>
              <td>3.417</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>   
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please look out this blog :
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/email-template-using-html-and-css/