# How to check if variable is array?... or something array-like

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I want to use a `foreach` loop with a variable, but this variable can be many different types, `NULL` for example.

So before `foreach` I test it:

```
if(is_array($var)){
  foreach($var as ...
```

But I realized that it can also be a class that implements `Iterator` interface. Maybe I am blind but how to check whether the class implements interface? Is there something like `is_a` function or `inherits` operator? I found `class_implements`, I can use it, but maybe there is something simpler?

And second, more important, I suppose this function exist, would be enough to check if the variable `is_array` or "implements `Iterator` interface" or should I test for something more?

Comment: if($var instanceof ArrayIterator)

Comment: Yeah, I was so sure this wouldn't work that haven't even looked to the manual...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterable objects and array type hinting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584700/iterable-objects-and-array-type-hinting)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

If you are using `foreach` inside a function and you are expecting an array or a [Traversable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) object you can type hint that function with:

```
function myFunction(array $a)
function myFunction(Traversable)
```

If you are not using `foreach` inside a function or you are expecting both [you can simply use this construct](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php#99195) to check if you can iterate over the variable:

```
if (is_array($a) or ($a instanceof Traversable))
```

Comment: Thanks. I hope it is enough and there are/will be no other language constructs that can be iterated.

Comment: I had found `is_array` to be expensive. The computational cost seemed to increase with the size of array (which makes no sense since it's just checking if it's an array). But it happened to me shockingly in a library. See [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358788/how-can-i-send-html-mails-with-included-css-with-phpmailer#comment68672222_2209829) in the linked question. Will `instanceof Traversable` work with arrays? I didn't get the chance to test its performance.

Comment: @ADTC AFAIR an array is an instance of `Traversable` so yes.

Comment: @Shoe I tried it [here](http://www.writephponline.com/). With `$var = array(1,2,3);` the results are: `is_array($var) = true` and `$var instanceof Traversable = false`.

Comment: @ADTC Yeah, just checked. Arrays do not implement `Iterator` and therefore don't work with `Traversable`.

Answer (score 15):

[*`foreach`*](https://php.net/foreach) can handle arrays and objects. You can check this with:

```
$can_foreach = is_array($var) || is_object($var);
if ($can_foreach) {
    foreach ($var as ...
}
```

You don't need to specifically check for [*`Traversable`*](https://php.net/Traversable) as others have hinted it in their answers, because all objects - like all arrays - are traversable in PHP.

More technically:

> `foreach` works with all kinds of traversables, i.e. with arrays, with plain objects (where the accessible properties are traversed) and `Traversable` objects (or rather objects that define the internal `get_iterator` handler).

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14854568/367456))

Simply said in common PHP programming, whenever a variable is

- an array
- an object

and *is not*

- NULL
- a resource
- a scalar

you can use *`foreach`* on it.

Answer (score 5):

You can check instance of `Traversable` with a simple function. This would work for all this of `Iterator` because `Iterator extends Traversable`

```
function canLoop($mixed) {
    return is_array($mixed) || $mixed instanceof Traversable ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: "? true : false" part is redundant. instanceof already gives a bool value as a result.

Answer (score 3):

PHP 7.1.0 [has introduced](https://secure.php.net/archive/2016.php#id2016-07-07-1) the [`iterable` pseudo-type and the `is_iterable()` function](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/iterable), which is specially designed for such a purpose:

> This […] proposes a new `iterable` pseudo-type. This type is analogous to `callable`, accepting multiple types instead of one single type.
>
> `iterable` accepts any `array` or object implementing `Traversable`. Both of these types are iterable using `foreach` and can be used with `yield` from within a generator.

```
function foo(iterable $iterable) {
    foreach ($iterable as $value) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

> This […] also adds a function `is_iterable()` that returns a boolean: `true` if a value is iterable and will be accepted by the `iterable` pseudo-type, `false` for other values.

```
var_dump(is_iterable([1, 2, 3])); // bool(true)
var_dump(is_iterable(new ArrayIterator([1, 2, 3]))); // bool(true)
var_dump(is_iterable((function () { yield 1; })())); // bool(true)
var_dump(is_iterable(1)); // bool(false)
var_dump(is_iterable(new stdClass())); // bool(false)
```

You can also use the function `is_array($var)` to check if the passed variable is an array:

```
<?php
    var_dump( is_array(array()) ); // true
    var_dump( is_array(array(1, 2, 3)) ); // true
    var_dump( is_array($_SERVER) ); // true
?>
```

Read more in [How to check if a variable is an array in PHP?](https://stackhowto.com/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-php/)

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$var = new ArrayIterator();

var_dump(is_array($var), ($var instanceof ArrayIterator));
```

returns `bool(false)` or `bool(true)`

Answer (score 0):

## Functions

```
<?php

/**
 * Is Array?
 * @param mixed $x
 * @return bool
 */
function isArray($x) : bool {
  return !isAssociative($x);
}

/**
 * Is Associative Array?
 * @param mixed $x
 * @return bool
 */
function isAssociative($x) : bool {
  if (!is_array($array)) {
    return false;
  }
  $i = count($array);
  while ($i > 0) {
    if (!isset($array[--$i])) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

## Example

```
<?php

$arr = [ 'foo', 'bar' ];
$obj = [ 'foo' => 'bar' ];

var_dump(isAssociative($arr));
# bool(false)

var_dump(isAssociative($obj));
# bool(true)

var_dump(isArray($obj));
# bool(false)

var_dump(isArray($arr));
# bool(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP 7.1 there is a pseudo-type [`iterable`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.iterable.php) for exactly this purpose. Type-hinting `iterable` accepts any array as well as any implementation of the `Traversable` interface.  PHP 7.1 also introduced the function [`is_iterable()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-iterable.php). For older versions, see other answers here for accomplishing the equivalent type enforcement without the newer built-in features.

Fair play: As BlackHole pointed out, this question appears to be a duplicate of [*Iterable objects and array type hinting?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584700/iterable-objects-and-array-type-hinting) and [his or her answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39320526/3303195) goes into further detail than mine.