# PHP Traversable type hint

Tags: php, arrays, php-7.1

I have a relatively simple function which uses a `foreach`

```
function foo($t) {
     $result;
     foreach($t as $val) {
         $result = dosomething($result, $val);
     }
     return $result;
}
```

I would like to type hint, and [`Traversable`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) seems to be the exact type hint I need

```
 function foo(Traversable $t) {
```

However this gives a `E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR` when using an array (which is of course usable in a `foreach`): [example](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/xc1-arr)

```
 Argument 1 passed to foo() must implement interface Traversable, array given
```

Is there a way to type hint or is this not possible?

Comment: From the manual (the link that you posted): `Abstract base interface that cannot be implemented alone. Instead it must be implemented by either IteratorAggregate or Iterator.`

Comment: I believe you can actually use `array` as the hint, I will test my theory, yes you can

Comment: @alfasin And as such any class implementing `Iterator` will also match `Traversable`, as `Iterator` is a subtype of `Traversable`. Basic OOP-mechanics

Comment: Please consider solution provided to the [comment in manual](http://pl1.php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php#99195). BTW, [I asked a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15603952/2088851).

Comment: @Dale I apologize in advance as I must be missing something: Array don't implement Iterator (AFAIK), and you're trying to use Array, no ?

Comment: @alfasin I was just mentioning you can use `array` as the type hint `function foo(array $array){}`

Comment: @Dale but array doesn't implement `Iterator` nor `Traversable`

Comment: @alfasin I didn't say that it does. I'm suggesting he uses array as the type hint, good bye.

Comment: Sorry - my last to comments were intended for @dtech not Dale...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterable objects and array type hinting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584700/iterable-objects-and-array-type-hinting)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

PHP 7.1 introduces the [`iterable` type declaration](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.iterable.php) for this purpose, which accepts both arrays and instances of `\Traversable`.

In previous versions, you'll have to omit the type declaration.

Answer (score 8):

There is a bug about this: [#41942](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=41942). Closed as 'not a bug'. As PHP arrays are not objects they cannot implement an interface and a such there is no way to type hint both `array` and `Traversable`.

You can use [`iterator_to_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php), [`ArrayIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php) or omit the type hint. Note that iterator_to_array will copy the whole iterator into an array an might thus be inefficient.

```
// These functions are functionally equivalent but do not all accept the same arguments
function foo(array $a) { foobar($a); }
function bar(Traversable $a) { foobar($a); }
function foobar($a) {
    foreach($a as $key => $value) {
    }
}

$array = array(1,2,3)
$traversable = new MyTraversableObject();

foo($array);
foo(iterator_to_array($traversable));

bar(new ArrayIterator($array));
bar($traversable);

foobar($array);
foobar($traversable);
```

Comment: You can also do `foo(new ArrayIterator(array(1,2,3))` to convert arrays to objects.

Answer (score 4):

Same problem. I've given up I simply manually code everything in the function.

This should give you the functionality you want:

```
function MyFunction($traversable)
{
    if(!$traversable instanceof Traversable && !is_array($traversable))
    {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
            'Myfunction($traversable = %s): Invalid argument $traversable.'
            ,var_export($traversable, true)
       ));
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

If you only want to display type of `$traversable`. And if you want the functionality inheritable in child classes.

```
public function MyMethod($traversable)
{
    if(!$traversable instanceof Traversable && !is_array($traversable))
    {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
            '%s::MyMethod($traversable): Invalid argument $traversable of type `%s`.'
            ,get_class($this)
            ,gettype($traversable)
       ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that arrays are no objects, so they can't implement an interface. So you can't type hint both, `array` and `Traversable`.

Comment: Are there other PHP native entities which are usable in `foreach` but do not implement `Traversable`?

Comment: No, but you can write your own class that implements `IteratorAggregate` or `Iterator`, and they extend `Traversable`

Comment: But there it is: all objects iterable in `foreach`. If the object implements `Traversable` the iterator (or the aggregated iterator) will be traversed, else the object's public properties http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php