# What's the function Traversable in PHP

Tags: php

[PHP Traversable type hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031720/php-traversable-type-hint)
i read this topic but i'm still confused about traversable, anyone can explain to me?
and explain about this function

```
function MyFunction($traversable)
{
  if(!$traversable instanceof Traversable && !is_array($traversable))
  {
    throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
        'Myfunction($traversable = %s): Invalid argument $traversable.'
        ,var_export($traversable, true)
   ));
 }
}
```

thanks

Comment: A "Traversable" object is an object that can be iterated in the same manner as an array, e.g. using a foreach() loop

Comment: but, what's the function of traversable?

Comment: The purpose of Traversable is to indicate that an object can be Traversed, or iterated, e.g. by using a foreach() loop