# Correct way to check (with PHP) a variable before looping through?

Tags: php, loops

Before looping through a variable (supposed to be an array)
I would make the following test:

```
if(
        !empty($arrJobs)    &&
        is_array($arrJobs)  &&
        count($arrJobs)
){
foreach ($arrJobs as $item) {
  //loop tasks
}
}
```

I've seen also using if(sizeof($arrJobs)>0) but in case $arrJobs isa  integer (I can't trust the input) it would be through and I will try looping through a integer...weird.

Is there a more concise and comprehensive way to perform this test before looping through the array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if variable is array?... or something array-like](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603952/how-to-check-if-variable-is-array-or-something-array-like)

Answer (score 1):

It is IMPORTANT to check if you're looping an ARRAY to FOREACH or else PHP will give you errors ... FOREACH expects parameter to be ARRAY..

You can use IS_ARRAY .. I believe that would be enough.

But checking it if empty would be VERY GOOD Practice... I'm using COUNT() to check if an ARRAY is empty.

Comment: INTERESTING answer

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check anything but `is_array`: if it's empty, PHP simply won't loop.

Moreover a suggestion: if those `if` had sense (not that case, but is helpful for this explanation) you should split with "early exit" (as coding style because it improves readability)

```
if (empty($arrJobs)) {
 return;
}

if (!is_array($arrJobs)) {
 return;
}

if (count($arrJobs)) {
 return;
}
```

Comment: do they have sense if you need to do something (or report something ) if array is empty? don't they?

Comment: @DonCallisto PHP has short-circuit condition evaluation, so after evaluation of first condition as false it skips other comparsions, so this "early-exit" is useless, just more code.

Comment: is_array seems to have some sense... if the variable has another type:   Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @JanHolas yes I *perfectly* know this ... Mine suggestion was about readability

Comment: on the other hand... even if PHP let you play dirty, it doesn't mean you shouldn't worry about writing  code in a solid flavour.(if it doesn't affect performance, and not adding garbage lines) IMHO

Comment: This "early exit suggestion" certainly does _not_ raise readability!

Comment: @DonCallisto I don't think it's more readble, but it's probably just matter of style and opinion. It might be usefull if you want to display different error message for each condition.

Comment: @koalaok no one let play you dirty: if something is array, so it's traversable, and it's empty, you should not check it *on purpose*. fullstop.

Comment: @KOALAOK.. check my answer below

Comment: @arkascha what if you have, let's say, ten `&&` condition?

Comment: @victor yep I agree with you. Upvoted and going to accept it. It would be great if php had a function that would check both is_array && !empty at the same time.

Comment: @Koalaok ... well you can create a function yourself... that would return a boolean... so you can just call that function in your if-statement .. and you can use it to your other projects.. .. make sense? :-)

Comment: @arkascha I think the right way for readability stays in the middle.

Comment: @victor makes sense. But it's annoying to have to complete a lang with utility function that could have been embedded :-)  So for my question sake the answer is test empty+is_array

Comment: @DonCallisto The _number_ of boolean conditions you concatenate does not lower readability. In contrary, blowing those checks up over a full page does. It is more a question of indentation. It is absolutely obvious to a programmer how those boolean operators behave. I personally place the `&&` (or whatever operator) at the _beginning_ of each line. That makes things crystal clear.

Comment: @Koalaok ... You Got It.. go kick some App!.. ;-)

Comment: @Koalaok ...  before I forgot.. you don't have to separate the condition.. you can use Logical && ... ;-)