# PHPMailer not including external css with Bootstrap 3

Tags: php, css, phpmailer

I have a PHPMailer script that sends an HTML Email (via the code to embed a HTML file).
The HTML file is a Bootstrap 3 page that references external CSS files for the bootstrap styling.

The Email works, and is received with images etc., but without any of the CSS.
Is there anything special I need to do, or is it not recommended?

There is a similar question here:  [How can I send HTML mails with included CSS with PHPMailer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358788/how-can-i-send-html-mails-with-included-css-with-phpmailer)
but as it's 4 years old, I thought perhaps things may have changed..?!

If not then I guess I'll have to reformat the Email to be HTML only without CSS.

Comment: Maybe that your mail client renders simple HTML with no CSS allowed?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105963/can-you-link-to-a-css-file-from-an-email) for more information.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2105975/998328 short answer: just embed the CSS you're using

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful answers, appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trizz & Carrie are correct -- most email clients that I'm aware of will block external scripts/stylesheets so your best bet is to include the styles you need at the top of the body of the HTML email.

```
<style type="text/css">

.some_class {
  /*styles here*/
}

.another_class {
  /*styles here*/
}

</style>

<!--now start your html for your email here-->
```

It's also best practice to give your style classes and ids really unique names to avoid conflict with built-in CSS naming conventions of various email platforms. You can test your code against a variety of email programs with a service like [Email on Acid](http://www.emailonacid.com/) (although this one is not free).