# Include a stylesheet into the PHP-Mail-Function

Tags: php, css, phpmailer

Is there a way to include a complete stylesheet within the email using PHPs `mail()` function to ensure the proper display of styles? I have a large stylesheet, specifically for CKEditor, that I need to include to ensure the correct styling in the email.

**EDIT**

I know that I could just copy the styles into an inline `<style>` tag. However, the CKEditor Style Sheet alone has over 10k lines, so I wouldn't think copying and pasting 10k lines is a good solution. So maybe there is another clever way to do this.

**Edit 2: Solution**

Using `file_get_contents('xyz.css')` is the solution I was looking for. It loads the content of the `.css`-file and I can simply wrap it with `<style>` and it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I send HTML mails with included CSS with PHPMailer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358788/how-can-i-send-html-mails-with-included-css-with-phpmailer)

Comment: Not really... Most of the links are outdated, etc... How can I include a stylesheet, if I don't want to link the absolute path?...

Comment: Simple: you shouldn't as most email clients will reject/ignore/throw out any stylesheet. Use inlined CSS.

Comment: @ChrisG that's not a good link for a dupe and as the OP stated, it's out of date and the accepted answer in there should be modified or deleted http://stackoverflow.com/a/358825/

Comment: I know i should use inlined CSS, but I can't do this for over 10.000 lines of Code (CKEditor Style Sheet)...

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Sorry man, just trying to be helpful. Where is the love??? Gykonik: Sorry, just trying to be helpful

Comment: well you have no choice. You should have thought about this before starting your project.

Comment: But... But... :c Is there any way, how to get the data from the stylesheets and paste them into <style></style>-Tags?

Answer (score 0):

As I know you have these options

1. Add [Internal Style Sheet](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_howto_internal)
2. [Inline Styles](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_howto_inline)
3. Or upload the css file to your host and share the like in email.

Not a best answer. Just For Your Information(**FYI**)

Comment: You can't reference external style sheets from emails. Internal or inline are your only choices.

Comment: @Synchro can do. If you use html format code so you can add src to link of your file you have hosted.

Comment: Nope. The clients will simply ignore it.

Comment: Actually clients dnt know about what we code. and what is the reason to ignore it ??

Answer (score 0):

Email template styles are very sensitive, that is, there are many more email clients than web browsers and they all display code differently.

If you have a stylesheet that's worth thousands of lines, you unfortunatly won't be able to simply include an external stylesheet and expect things to look uniform between different email clients.

Your best bet is to start the template from scratch using a boilerplate template and recreate the stylesheet rules the best you can.

EDIT: simple email template boilerplate to start https://github.com/seanpowell/Email-Boilerplate

Comment: How would it be, if I copy all CSS-Code in the Mail function? :s

Answer (score 0):

That duplicate question is not outdated - everything in it is still true. The way you include styles in email (what you asked) has not changed at all - what styles you put in may have, but that's a different question. I'd suggest you look at an email CSS framework like [Zurb's Foundation for email](http://zurb.com/article/1420/foundation-for-emails-2-making-html-email).